# Should I supply my references to a recruiter before the interview

Tags: recruitment

I've applied for a really good role through a recruitment agency. The recruiter has asked me to supply the names and phone numbers of 2 professional references before he will submit my cv to the employer.

Although I have good references I'm afraid that if I did this for every role I applied for, my referees would soon get sick of providing me good references.

I've told him that I need to check with my referees first before I give them to him, but I really don't want them being called until I'm close to being offered the position.

What should I do?

Comment: What you do is don't use a recruitment agency. I wouldn't be surprised if THEY call your references to gain an understanding of you're worth working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with an agency you trust, the role is really good, and your recruiter is asking to submit references with your CV, you should probably provide references. Employers generally won't bother to contact references until late in the hiring process, so unless you are expecting to reach that point in many interviews you probably don't have to worry about your references being annoyed.

If you are still concerned about reference fatigue, consider using letters of recommendation to submit with you CV instead, so that interviewers can get the gist without needing to verify references until absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is sketchy.

Will they use this information to submit potential candidates to your references?

Ask them, point blank.

If you don't know this recruiter, or if this recruiter wasn't recommended to you, I would not submit that information to them.

However, if the client company trusted this 3rd party recruiter enough to give them an email address with the domain name of the company, then I would go ahead and share that information assuming my references were ok with it.

Comment: You can ask them point blank, but I wouldn't trust their answer.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, I agree.